# DRF use related model field for lookup

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use related model field for lookup

tried this but getting error.

```
class SubscriptionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SubscriptionSerializer
    queryset = Subscription.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'newsletter_slug'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'newsletter_slug'

class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    newsletter_slug = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        source='newsletter', read_only=True, slug_field='slug'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
```

Error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'newsletter_slug' into field.`

Comment: Please post your models. I don't think it's possible to use calculated fields as lookup fields.

Comment: It was my mistake instead of `newsletter_slug` it should be `newsletter__slug`

Comment: Sorry didn't read the comments before answering. Feel free to answer yourself and accept that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your lookup field needs to be specified in the form that QuerySet operations like `filter`expect, so you'd use

```
lookup_field = 'newsletter__slug'
```